# Was this incident in Captain America: Civil War officially confirmed to be a consequence of Spider-Man’s Spidey sense?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, captain-america-civil-war

When Spider-Man is fighting Bucky and Falcon during the airport scene in *Captain America: Civil War*, Bucky (*apparently*) throws door at Spider-Man.

Spidey instinctively ducks avoiding the door from hitting him. There are theories about this being the **spider-sense** warning him about imminent danger..

But was this incident officially confirmed (by writers/producers or anyone) to be the first occurrence of the Spider-sense in the MCU?

Comment: There's nothing of any use in the film's official audio commentary

Answer (score 11):

There was an interview right after Spider-Man: Homecoming, where Kevin Feige confirmed that this Spidey does have the spider-sense.

> I recently asked Marvel Studios president and Homecoming producer
>   Kevin Feige if the Spider-sense exists in the MCU or if the need for
>   such a super-power was negated thanks to Spidey's costume now being
>   decked out with AI and other Stark tech that aids him in exploring his
>   surroundings.
>
> "No, I think he has it. And I think he has it with or without that
>   suit," Feige told IGN. "I think how we explore it in a cinematic sense
>   will change. I mean, that was sort of a big showy part of previous
>   versions and we thought that we'd make it more of an internal, sort of
>   second nature thing for him."
>
> Feige continued, "But there are ways coming up that will slowly hint
>   at that and also just make it part of his, you know, his natural
>   abilities. But we don't know that if it will be -- I think we'll
>   explore it further down the line, but [it's] definitely him not the
>   suit."
>
> - [Kevin Feige to IGN](https://in.ign.com/spider-man-marvel/110187/news/spider-man-homecoming-producer-kevin-feige-on-whether-the-sp)

If that is the case, we can safely conclude that this version of Spider-Man *does* indeed have the spider-sense.

So by extension, his "reflexes" in Civil War would certainly be an outcome of the spider-sense.

So far that I was able to search, I did not find any commentary specifically on that incidence in Civil War.

Comment: He see his arm hairs raise in infinity war. Many assume that is his spider sense.

Comment: @JackBNimble Yes, I too believe that was a subtle indication of spidey sense.